# Previous Bootstrap Carousel Image sees through as slides

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I added a 2nd Carousel to the bottom of my page but now my original Carousel previous image is ghosting as it slides to the next. I double check all my code and it looks fine. Any ideas would be appreciated. This is the site: [vmzsoftsolutions][1] By the way both carousels have a different id and the java scripts are referencing accordingly. I also check the image sizes and they all are the same sizes. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you

```js
   <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    })
    </script>
  
  <!-- Script for Carousel2 -->
    <script>
    $('#myCarousel2').carousel({
  interval: 5000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  
  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
  else {
   $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
  </script>
    <!-- Script for Carousel2 -->
```

```html
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="height:400px">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
      
      <div class="item active">
      <div class="fill" style="background-image: url(_images/Rowing_S.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption" id="cap">
      <h1 class="mission-statement col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-2" style="font-family: lato; font-style: normal; font-weight: 800; text-shadow: -2px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1.00); font-size: 37px;">WEB DEVELOPMENT SOLUTIONS </h1>
      <h2 class="company col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-4" style="font-family: lato; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; color: #ffffff;"> Where precision triumphs speed</h2>
      <h2><a href="about.html" class="btn btn-default btn-car1">Learn More</a></h2>
      </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="item">
      <div class="fill" style="background-image: url(_images/Bridge.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption" id="cap-2">
      <h1 class="social-networks" style="font-family: lato; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; font-size: 50px;">SOCIAL NETWORKS </h1>
      <h2 class="customers" style="font-weight: 300"> Connecting your customers to your business</h2>
      <h3><a href="services.html" class="btn btn-default btn-social">Learn More</a></h3>
      </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="item">
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(_images/Mobile1.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption" id="cap-3">
      <h1 class="mobile" style="font-family: lato; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; font-size: 50px;">MOBILE APPS </h1>
      <h2 class="customers"> Accessing your Applications on the go has never been easier</h2>
      <h2><a href="services.html#service-two" class="btn btn-default btn-mobile-car">Learn More</a></h2>
      </div>
      </div>
             
      <div class="item">
      <div class="fill" style="background-image: url(_images/Portfolio1.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption" id="cap-4">
      <h1 class="mobile" style="font-family: lato; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; font-size: 50px;"></h1>
      <h2 class="portfolio"> Our work so far</h2>
      <h2><a href="portfolio.html" class="btn btn-default" id="portfoliio-btn">Learn More</a></h2>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev scroll-icons"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next scroll-icons"></span>
        </a>
    </header>`      <div class="row" id="portfolio-row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" id="col-portfolio-title">
        <h2 class="page-header" id="page-header-portfolio">Portfolio</h2>
         </div>
         
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel2">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="whittieradhc.html"><img src="_images/whittieradh_edit.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="pizzaroni_mobile.html"><img src="_images/PortfolioPizza1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="MHCourier_ResponsiveSite.html"><img src="_images/Portfolio6.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="MHCourier_Access_DB.html"><img src="_images/MHCourier_OrderEntry_2_2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="vocinnovations.html"><img src="_images/Portfolio5.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-4"><a href="elite.html"><img src="_images/Portfolio6.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show a fiddle or at least a working example

Comment: Is under the domain vmzsoftsolutions.com

Comment: I see what you mean. Have you included all files, especially `bootstrap.js` and JQuery?

Comment: I do have both but seems they are older versions. jQuery v1.11.1  & Bootstrap v3.3.4. Also my script for Bootstrap is using the.min.js version. Do you think if update to 11.3.3 and Bootstrap 4  may fix the issue or would that may do more harm than good?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is still in alpha, so I doubt you'd benefit from it

Comment: I added the jquery-1.11.3.min.js and still having the same issue. Looks like the previous slide is transparent somehow. I check the controllers, the slides images and captions  transparency but nothing that i notice there.